# How to remove Substring from substring start until the end of the string in Java

Tags: java, cookies, replace, substring, rest-assured

I have a method using RestAssured that establishes the bearer token and it establishes the detailed cookies that I need to include in request headers for other API endpoints.

When I call cookies.getDetailedCookies.toString() I get the below (where cookies variable represents Rest Assured Http Cookie):

"amlbcookie=01;Path=/;Domain=mydomain.com;Secure;HttpOnly
tvgauthcookie=C6nl2pVadONSclRAaL1gxWd2-60.*AAJTSQACMDYAAlNLABxFOTFSWk1nUW9Td1NJOHhrSHppUW1FUHdKdG89AAR0eXBlAANDVFMAAlMxAAIwMQ..*;Path=/;Domain=mydomain.com;Secure;HttpOnly
**BIGipServerqavgamws-https-pool=1234567890.12345.0000;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly**"

One problem is that in Postman when I add the bearer token in Authorization header, it automatically gets the necessary cookies and is shown in the Cookie header as seen below.  I am not seeing the **BIGipServerqavgamws-https-pool=1234567890.12345.0000;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly** in the Postman Cookie header value (I suppose it is a browser session cookie which is not needed for submitting the request via Postman):

[image]

Is there a way to remove this particular cookie using java Starting with BIG* until the end of the string?

Comment: Can you show full stacktrace?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I have now added the full stack trace.

Comment: After looking at it, it looks like the 3rd cookie starting with "BIG" is what I need to remove.  In this case, how do I remove that from the cookies string mentioned, starting with BIG and until the end of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove string from `BIG..` to end of String, you can simply do this:

```
String cookies = ...;
String sub = cookies.replaceAll(" BIG(.+)", ""); //also remove white space before BIG
//System.out.println(sub);
```